# How to i resolve this error while starting to use owasp

Tags: sql-server, mysqli, xampp, owasp

I was trying to use owasp for the first time on kali as root@kali. The installation was ok but when i tried to enter the webpage this error showed up on the top.
Could anyone help in resolving the error?

Below is the error and the warning that I am getting in localhost

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 239

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 245








Tried clicking setup/reset the DB but ended up with this 


HTML 5 Local and Session Storage cleared unless error popped-up already.

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/owasp-esapi-php/lib/apache-log4php/trunk/src/main/php/helpers/LoggerPatternParser.php on line 156

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 128

Notice: Undefined variable: ACCESS_DENIED in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 130

Warning: substr_count(): Empty substring in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 130
Attempting to connect to MySQL server on host 127.0.0.1 with user name root

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 128

Notice: Undefined variable: ACCESS_DENIED in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 130

Warning: substr_count(): Empty substring in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 130
Connected to MySQL server at 127.0.0.1 as root
Preparing to drop database mutillidae
Error was reported while attempting to drop database mutillidae
MySQL sometimes throws errors attempting to drop databases. Here is error in case the error is serious.
Error Message

Failure is always an option
Line    216
Code    0
File    /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php
Message /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 211: Error executing query:

connect_errno: 0
errno: 1010
error: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './mutillidae', errno: 39 "Directory not empty")
client_info: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $
host_info: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP

) Query: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mutillidae (0) [Exception]
Trace   #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php(309): MySQLHandler->doExecuteQuery('DROP DATABASE I...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/set-up-database.php(58): MySQLHandler->executeQuery('DROP DATABASE I...') #2 {main}
Diagnotic Information   DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mutillidae
Click here to reset the DB

Preparing to create database mutillidae
Error Message

Failure is always an option
Line    216
Code    0
File    /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php
Message /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php on line 211: Error executing query:

connect_errno: 0
errno: 1007
error: Can't create database 'mutillidae'; database exists
client_info: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $
host_info: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP

) Query: CREATE DATABASE mutillidae (0) [Exception]
Trace   #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/classes/MySQLHandler.php(309): MySQLHandler->doExecuteQuery('CREATE DATABASE...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mutillidae/set-up-database.php(74): MySQLHandler->executeQuery('CREATE DATABASE...') #2 {main}
Diagnotic Information   CREATE DATABASE mutillidae
```

Click here to reset the DB

Comment: OWASP is an organization. It includes loads of very different projects, so it would be helpful if you could state which OWASP project you are actually using.

Comment: You can try to create a new database (using phpmyadmin), then set up database connection in mutillidae/includes/database-config.php.